# Get a hash into a Jekyll Liquid template from a Plugin for use in the FOR loop?

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll, liquid

This one's got me stumped...

I'd like to share a YAML hash from a single file among a few other Jekyll pages.

I know you can put it in the Front Matter (which would require duplicating it), and I know you can generate (write) pages via a plugin (but I'm using it in a few different types of pages, which would be complex). Neither is what I'm looking for.

I'd like to loop over the hash with Liquid in my pages, but I can't seem to get the hash from the plugin to Liquid. `{% capture %}` only works with strings and `{% assign %}` won't let you call a tag within itself, like `{% assign projects = gethash %}` where `gethash` is a custom Liquid tag.

Basically, I'd like to use the separate YAML file like a text-based database.

YAML File has this in it:

```
projects:

  category1:
     -
       title: Project 1
       desc: Description
       etc...
     -
       title: Project 2
       etc...

    category2:
     -
       title: Project 3
       desc: Description
       etc...
     -
       title: Project 4
       etc...
```

Plugin is calling (which gives a Ruby Hash of the YAML):

```
def...
  YAML::load(File.read('projects.yml'))
end...
```

And in template, I want to:

```
{% for p in projects %}
  ...
```

This should be really simple, but it's one of those Liquid things that is a pain.

How can you get a hash into Liquid from a plugin for use in the `{% for %}` loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the solution that I came up:

A **Jekyll Plugin** that create's a Liquid Tag: `yaml_to_liquid`. This plugin parses the yaml file into a hash and then adds it to the Jekyll `page` variable.

```rb
module Jekyll

  class YamlToLiquid < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, arg, tokens)
      super

      if arg.length == 0
        raise 'Please enter a yaml file path'
      else
        @yml_path = arg
      end
    end

    def render(context)

      yml = YAML::load(File.read(@yml_path))
      context.registers[:page]['yml'] = yml
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('yaml_to_liquid', Jekyll::YamlToLiquid)
```

To use it. Place the tag at the top of your `.html` or `.md` page just below the **Yaml Front Matter** and then access the `yml` variable as usual. This loop will only output the `code` hash (allows you to access the whole hash or just sub-hashes):

```
---
layout: page
---
{% yaml_to_liquid work/_projects.yml %}

<ul>
  {% for n in page.yml.projects.code %}
    <li>
    <a href="{{ n.url }}">{{ n.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Example of `work/_projects.yml`:

```rb
projects:

  code:
    - title:
      url:

    - title:
      url:

  websites:
    - title:
      url:

    - title:
      url:
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't need it to be a plugin, it can be put in your `_config.yml`. For a plugin, you might need to append the hash to the `site` variable.

I think that a generator would suffice. There is [a page about plugins](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/) that you should take a look.

This is what I'd use (I can't test right now, so it might be wrong!):

```
module Jekyll
  class ProjectsGenerator < Generator
    safe true

    def generate(site)
      # This probably won't work.
      site.projects = YAML::load(File.read('projects.yml'))
    end
  end
end
```

Anyway, I really think that if you don't need the extra complexity (having a separate file, creating a new plugin just for you, etc), just put the data in `_config.yml`. Simplicity is good.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks @agarie. How would one append to the `site` var in a plugin and access that in a template? I made a plugin (http://pastebin.com/x1ahiwhj) the loads the YAML and processes the template. This is not ideal, and appending to site would be better.

Comment: Hi @agarie, thank you for the update. I've contributed to Jekyll and have read the plugins page and also created a few. So I just need a focused solution to appending to the site var. I don't want to put the data in _config.yml, as there will be a few hashes of different data and it's better for me to have them in their own respective files, it's not complex at all, however, appending to site (or page) from a plugin seems to be...